# What is the domain of the function $x^{\log_x\pi}$?

Tags: functions

What is the domain of the function $f(x)=x^{\log_x\pi}$?

$x^{\log_x\pi}=x^{\frac{\log \pi}{\log x}}$.

Will $x=1,0$ come in the domain of $f(x)?$Will $(0,1)$ be the part of the domain of $f(x)$?I am not sure what should be its correct domain?Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The domain is determined by

1. $x>0$
2. $\log x \neq 0$.

Hence $x \in (0,1) \cup (1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

We can write $f(x) = x^{\log_{x}(\pi)} =\pi^{\log_{x}{x}} = \pi$

Where $x>0$ and $x\neq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, logarithms is defined for positive real numbers,

Now, we have $x^{\log_x\pi}$
$$\log_{x}\pi=\frac{1}{\log_{\pi} x}$$
now, we have the following conditions

1. $x>0$
2. $\log_{\pi}x\neq 0\implies x\neq 1$

Hence, combining the conditions above, the domain of $x^{\log_x \pi}$ is given as $$\color{red}{x\in(0, 1)\cup (1, \infty)}$$